# Change the current URL of a specific Firefox tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, webrequest, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a Firefox add-on that intercepts HTML requests, exactly as outlined in the [Mozilla tutorial here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests). Whenever it intercepts a request it calls a callback function `logURL(details)` where `details` contains the `tabId` of the tab that originated the request (among other things).

What I would like to be able to do is modify the tab that originated the request, specifically to set its URL to something new. Everything I've found that seems vaguely related to this task on the Mozilla website (e.g. [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Tabbed_browser#Getting_access_to_the_browser)) has been marked obsolete.

How can you set a tab's URL to something new given its tab ID within an add-on?

Comment: The link that you provided to the page on Tabbed browser, is considered obsolete, which should be clear from the page. Unless you are specifically working on a non-WebExtension add-on, you should stick to only things in the [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) hierarchy and normal Web APIs. There are multiple types of [Firefox add-ons](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/introduction-to-firefox-add-ons/13574/introduction). WebExtensions can use almost nothing of what was available for other types of add-ons.

Comment: @Makyen Sorry, I accidentally left that sentence incomplete, I guess I got distracted while searching for the link. I meant to say that everything I've found in the docs that seems related has been marked obsolete like you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the things which can be done with [`tabs.update()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/update).  If you want to navigate the tab with the ID `tabId` to the URL contained in `newUrl`, then you could do the following:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabId,{url: newUrl});
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great.